# Squeeze double char in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to squeeze multicharacter in string ?

```
Example:
hahahahahaha => ha
lalalala => la
awdawdawdawd => awd

str.squeeze("ha")  # doesn't work
str.tr("haha", "ha") # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def squeeze(s)
  s.gsub(/(.+?)\1+/, '\1')
end

puts squeeze('hahahaha')                  # => 'ha'
puts squeeze('awdawdawd')                 # => 'awd'
puts squeeze('hahahaha something else')   # => 'ha something else'
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work with for ex. : "hahahaha something else"

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex based search and replace:

```
str.gsub(/(ha)+/, 'ha')
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but with this I have to define strings that should be squeezing